# How to open Chrome Extension's side panel clicking a button inside the popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and want to use the recently added [chrome.sidePanel API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/sidePanel) to open the side panel and show my chrome extension there when a user click a button inside the extension's popup.

I have tried the following code:

App.tsx

```
const handleOpenSidePanel = async () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    const currentTabId = tabs[0].id;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'openSidePanel', tabId: currentTabId });
  });
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, tab) => {
  if (message.type === "openSidePanel") {
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ windowId: tab.windowId});
  }
});
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
  "sidePanel",
  "tabs"
],
"side_panel": {
  "default_path": "index.html"
}
...
```

When I click on the button, I get the following error and the side panel doesn't open:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: At least one of "tabId" and "windowId" must be provided`

Comment: 1) `message, tab` should be `message, {tab}`, but it won't work anyway because the popup doesn't have a tab, it's a special window not related to the tab. 2) There's no need for messages and the background script here as you can directly call chrome.sidePanel.open in the popup app.

Comment: Calling `chrome.sidePanel?.open()` directly in the popup file (`App.tsx`) returns `Property 'sidepanel' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.ts(2339)`

Comment: It's just a linter error. Simply use a better chrome types package e.g. the [official one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types).

Comment: @wOxxOm `chrome.sidePanel` is not supposed to be called in the application file level, but on the background/service worker. Read https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/sidePanel. There are no examples of the API being called at the application level.

Comment: No, all `chrome` API can be called by any extension page that has chrome-extension:// URL, which means the action popup can do it too. You can suggest to add this info to all documentation pages because looking back indeed quite a few people share the same misconception. BTW there's no such thing as "application file level" in chrome extensions.